# Why my scrollable div doesn't work inside a Bootstrap modal?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, html

I have problem that is driving me crazy. I have a simple DIV which I want to convert into a scrollable one. It have a table inside it and it should be very easy. I got a separated .html file with my code and it works well.

Here is:

```
   <div id="agreement_rate_multiple_view" style="overflow:scroll; height:100px; width:500px;">
                             <table id="agreement_rates_list" >
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th style="background-color: #CCCCCC">
                                            Quantity
                                        </th>
                                        <th style="background-color: #CCCCCC">
                                            Amount
                                        </th>
                                        <th style="background-color: #CCCCCC">
                                            Effective Date
                                        </th>
                                        <th style="background-color: #CCCCCC">
                                            ExpirationDate
                                        </th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>

                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="text-align: center">
                                            <input type="text" style="width:80px;" id="agreement_charges_edit_quantity0"  />
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="text-align: center">
                                            <input type="text" style="width:80px;" id="agreement_charges_edit_amount0"  />
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="text-align: center">
                                            <input type="date" style="width:125px;" id="agreement_charges_effectiveDate_edit0" />
                                         </td>
                                        <td style="text-align: center">
                                            <input type="date" style="width:125px;" id="agreement_charges_expirationDate_edit0" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="text-align: center">
                                            <input type="text" style="width:80px;" id="agreement_charges_edit_quantity1"  />
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="text-align: center">
                                            <input type="text" style="width:80px;" id="agreement_charges_edit_amount1"  />
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="text-align: center">
                                            <input type="date" style="width:125px;" id="agreement_charges_effectiveDate_edit1" />
                                         </td>
                                        <td style="text-align: center">
                                            <input type="date" style="width:125px;" id="agreement_charges_expirationDate_edit1" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="text-align: center">
                                            <input type="text" style="width:80px;" id="agreement_charges_edit_quantity2"  />
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="text-align: center">
                                            <input type="text" style="width:80px;" id="agreement_charges_edit_amount2"  />
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="text-align: center">
                                            <input type="date" style="width:125px;" id="agreement_charges_effectiveDate_edit2" />
                                         </td>
                                        <td style="text-align: center">
                                            <input type="date" style="width:125px;" id="agreement_charges_expirationDate_edit2" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="text-align: center">
                                            <input type="text" style="width:80px;" id="agreement_charges_edit_quantity3"  />
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="text-align: center">
                                            <input type="text" style="width:80px;" id="agreement_charges_edit_amount3"  />
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="text-align: center">
                                            <input type="date" style="width:125px;" id="agreement_charges_effectiveDate_edit3" />
                                         </td>
                                        <td style="text-align: center">
                                            <input type="date" style="width:125px;" id="agreement_charges_expirationDate_edit3" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="text-align: center">
                                            <input type="text" style="width:80px;" id="agreement_charges_edit_quantity4"  />
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="text-align: center">
                                            <input type="text" style="width:80px;" id="agreement_charges_edit_amount4"  />
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="text-align: center">
                                            <input type="date" style="width:125px;" id="agreement_charges_effectiveDate_edit4" />
                                         </td>
                                        <td style="text-align: center">
                                            <input type="date" style="width:125px;" id="agreement_charges_expirationDate_edit4" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
```

That's works flawless.

Now, the problem is that, this div shows up in a Bootstrap modal, and it seems that for some reason, because this div is inside of some other divs, maybe the div that suppose to be scrollable, behaves according to other CSS class.

But that don't suppose to happen because I'm using inline CSS for this one!!!

Here is a screenshot of the scrollable div, working ok in a separated .html page:

[image: Working Scrollable Div]

Now, here is a screenshot of the very same div, but this time, showing up in the Bootstrap modal:

[image: Scrollable div not working]

Something force the div to take the table height and it doesn't even show the scrollbar either!

Here is a link to my Skydrive when you can see the original .aspx

[Original .aspx file](http://1drv.ms/NKudAT)

Is there a way to force my inline CSS to work? Any help will be GREATLY appreciate and sorry for my English. It is not my native language.

Comment: Try `overflow:scroll !important;` this will override all other properties.

Comment: Overflow:scroll is already implemented in the div!! It is in the first line of code that I pasted here :(

Comment: add `!important` after `scroll`.

Comment: Ok sorry, I didn't see that. I did...... and still doesn't work. It still behaves like I posted in the second screenshot :/

Answer (score -2):

am not sure how far this will work.. please try.. :)

```
#agreement_rate_multiple_view {
    overflow:scroll !important; 
    height:100px; 
    width:auto; 
}
```

Comment: Somebody voted down your answer but wasn't me. Now... I don't really understand where I can implement that line of code with those bracket.

Did you mean: 

<div id="agreement_rate_multiple_view" style="overflow:scroll !important; height:100px; width:auto;"> ??

Comment: Oh, you mean, in the CSS... but the problem is that, that would be  exactly the same as inline CSS!!. Some people are voting down the answer but they don't tell why. I will try it anyway.